why I can't put my hyperlink on the right side
my code is "中 and the text-align is not work on link only which meant text-align can work on everywhere except
the character should be show on the right side on the page which I was expect to do.Therefore I want to ask how to dix with this problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
